# How to access data file present with the client and process it?

Tags: python, api, flask

What I'm trying to achieve is the following:

- Design an API which receives data from the client, processes it and then prints a small table.

How can I access the file data?
- I'm asking the client to send me the location of the file but that doesn't work. Please suggest a suitable approach.

The code for the API is follows:

```
import pandas as pd
from flask import Flask, request,render_template
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/<path:fileN>', methods=['GET'])
def my_form_post(fileN):
    f=open(fileN,"r")
    #f=os.read(fileN,os.O_RDONLY)
    lines=f.readlines()
    ff=[]
    for line in lines:
        parts=line.split("\t")
        parts=parts[:7]
        ff.append(parts)
    pd.set_option("display.colheader_justify","center")
    df=pd.DataFrame(ff,columns=['Date', 'Start Time', 'Time', '# of Req', 'HTTP Method', 'Link','HTTP Response'])
    df=df[df['Link'].str.startswith('/ic/')==True]
    df.sort_values(by="Time", axis=0, ascending=False, inplace=True)
    df.reset_index(inplace=True)
    df.drop(['index'], axis=1, inplace=True)
    df.index+=1
    df=df.head(5)
    html=df.to_html()
    return html

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, threaded=True, debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

To receive file you need to use POST method and retrieve the file from request like this:

```
file = request.files['file']
```

> Note that files will only contain data if the request method was POST, PUT or PATCH and the  that posted to the request had enctype="multipart/form-data". It will be empty otherwise. You can check [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Request.files) for more details.